# Reverse nested aggregation in date histogram ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have some problems combining data from different levels in the date histogram.
Elastic documentation [gives](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.1/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) an example that helps to deal with the case when the date in histogram is retrieved from the current level of nesting and aggregation uses the level upper, so `reverse_nested` helps. But what to do if the situation is mirrored? Like the aggregation uses the current level of nesting and date lives on the uppers level?

Let's say I have the next data structure:

```
  {
    "_source": {
      "order_uuid": "...",
      "created_at": "...",
      "status": "...",
      "subtotal": 100,
      "items": [
        {
          "item_id": 1,
          "price": 1000,
          "units": 1,
        }
      ],
    }
  }
```

And I want to have date histogram with `created_at` field for each item. So I want to have smth like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "items": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "items"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "data": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "items.item_id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "reversed": {
              "aggs": {
                "sales_per_day": {
                  "date_histogram": {
                    "reverse_nested": {},
                    "field": "created_at", #<- not nested
                    "calendar_interval": "day",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "units_sum": {
                      "sum": {"field": "items.units"} #<- nested
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This example doesn't work obviously because you can't use `reverse_nested` inside `date_histogram` (at least I don't know how) but it gives the impression of what I what it to be.

Does anyone have ideas on how to deal with it without reorganizing the mapping? Ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you must specify somthing like this. First you specify reverse_nested aggregation and then in sub aggregation you use date_historgram on your not nested field

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "items": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "items"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "data": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "items.item_id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "reversed": {
              "reverse_nested": {
              }, 
              "aggs": {
                "sales_per_day": {
                  "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "created_at",
                    "calendar_interval": "day"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "units_sum": {
                      "sum": {"field": "items.units"}
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```